PermissionError When Importing typing_extensions in Python Script Executed from SQL Server Agent
I am encountering a PermissionError when attempting to execute a Python script via SQL Server Agent. The script works fine in PyCharm and from the command line, but when run as a job I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Scripts\generate_documentation.py", line 1, in <module>
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
File "C:\Program Files\Python313\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 12, in 
<module>
from . import util as _util
File "C:\Program Files\Python313\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 
15, in <module>
from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg as coerce_generator_arg
File "C:\Program Files\Python313\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", 
line 39, in <module>
from .typing import is_non_string_iterable
File "C:\Program Files\Python313\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\typing.py", line 38, 
in <module>
from typing_extensions import Annotated as Annotated  # 3.8
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1022, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1159, in get_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1217, in get_data
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program 
Files\\Python313\\Lib\\site-packages\\typing_extensions.py'

Environment:

Python version: 3.13.1
SQL Server version: 2022
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro

Setup:

Python is installed in C:\Program Files\Python313
All required packages (SQLAlchemy, Pandas, Jinja2, etc.) are installed in C:\Program Files\Python313\Lib\site-packages

Agent Job Command
"C:\Program Files\Python313\python.exe" 
 C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Scripts\generate_documentation.py

The SQLSERVERAGENT service has read and execute permissions on the C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Scripts folder, and I ensured the folder and Python installation have the necessary permissions.
How can I resolve this PermissionError when running the script via SSMS?

SSMS doesn't run Python scripts though; it's an IDE for connecting to SQL Server. Are you using some kind of extension? What is the script you are running?

Grant more permissions to the agent account, or configure a Agent proxy to run the job as a user who has the correct permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15

@ThomA I am not directly running the Python script within SSMS itself. Instead, I have created a SQL Server Agent Job that executes the Python script using the following command: "C:\Program Files\Python313\python.exe" C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Scripts\generate_documentation.py

So SSMS has nothing to with the problem

What type of step are you using? Powershell?

I'm using the Operating system (CmdExec) step type.
I tried to create a simple test job to generate a .txt file with the following code:
with open("print.txt", "w") as file:       file.write("Hello, World!\n")
However, I get the following error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'print.txt'
